# Traversing Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to traverse Binary search tree with the follwoing code and my recursion is just taking care of Right side if the tree, which I see why But what should I do to improve the logic here?

```
public void Print() {
    Console.WriteLine(this.Value + "  ");
    if (this.Right != null) {
        this.Right.Print();
    }
    if (this.Left != null) {
        this.Left.Print();
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific error occurring here?  Also, why do you have a read inside of your print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that you are reading from the console at the end of the function. When the code gets to the bottom of the tree on the right, it executes `Console.Read()` and won't continue printing the rest of the tree until it gets something.

Eliminate that and it should print everything.

Comment: I see what you are saying and your suggestion actually worked. Thank you so much for that. But I have a question. My console.Read is actually after    this.Left.Print();. Then why is this behavior? Second question, This code produced the results then what kind of traversal is this? Pre, Post or IN irder?

Comment: Think through what's happening. You recursively call `Print()` on the right side first. When there finally is no right or left child (which happens at the bottom of the right-most node, I take it), it finally calls its first `Read()`. If you entered something through the console then, it would return, the next `Print()` on the stack would regain control, and would try to `Read()` again (or some node on its left subtree would).

Comment: As to your second question, this is a modified preorder. The node value is printed before the subtrees are printed. It's modified because the subtrees are usually visited left-to-right. (I guess if you're in a country that writes with a right-to-left script, then the usual way would be the "modified" version. :-))

Comment: Lols.. I see your point. BTW in in a Left to right country... But anyways my confusion was due to ingnorance towards the fact that Console.Read() actually stops the execution and wait for use input rather than continuing the execution.... Thank you so much for a clear explanations. You rock!!